# cut columns and rbind it with dataframe in r

Tags: r, dplyr

My data has several duplicate columns and I want to cut the duplicate columns and rbind it.

I have done this in my code, but I wonder if there is a more efficient way to do this.

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:4,
             b = 5:8,
             a.1 = letters[1:4],
             b.1 = letters[5:8],
             a.2 = LETTERS[1:4],
             b.2 = LETTERS[5:8])
names(df)[c(1,3,5)] <- "a"
names(df)[c(2,4,6)] <- 'b'

d1 <- df[,1:2]
d2 <- df[,3:4]
d3 <- df[,5:6]
d <- rbind(d1,d2) %>% rbind(d3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another base R option is to use `split.default` and split the dataframe based on `names` of the column, `unlist` them and `cbind` individual lists.

```
do.call(cbind.data.frame, lapply(split.default(df, names(df)), unlist))

#     a b
#a1   1 5
#a2   2 6
#a3   3 7
#a4   4 8
#a.11 a e
#a.12 b f
#a.13 c g
#a.14 d h
#a.21 A E
#a.22 B F
#a.23 C G
#a.24 D H
```

You can set rownames to `NULL` if it is not needed. Also reading characters as characters and not factors by setting `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** An option is loop through the `unique` `names` of the dataset, subset the dataset columns based on that, `unlist` and set the row names to `NULL`

```
out <- as.data.frame(sapply(unique(names(df)), 
        function(x) unlist(df[names(df) ==x])))
row.names(out) <- NULL
out
#   a b
#1  1 5
#2  2 6
#3  3 7
#4  4 8
#5  a e
#6  b f
#7  c g
#8  d h
#9  A E
#10 B F
#11 C G
#12 D H
```

---

**2)** Or another option is to create the `data.frame` by selecting alternate columns

```
data.frame(a = unlist(df[c(TRUE, FALSE)]), b = unlist(df[c(FALSE, TRUE)]))
```

---

**3)** Or `unlist` the data, create a logical condition based on the names, and then subset the vector to create the `data.frame`

```
v1 <- unlist(df)
i1 <- grepl("a", names(v1))
data.frame(a = v1[i1], b = v1[!i1])
```

---

**4a)** Or with `split.default`

```
do.call(rbind, split.default(df, cumsum(names(df) == "a")))
```

**4b)** Using `%%`

```
do.call(rbind, split.default(df, cumsum(seq_along(df) %% 2)))
```

**5)** Using `seq` and `lapply`

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(1, ncol(df), by = 2), function(i) df[i:(i+1)]))
```

---

**6)** Or with `split.default` and `bind_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(split.default(df, cumsum(names(df) == "a")))
```

---

**7)** Or with `split.default` and `rbindlist`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(split.default(df, cumsum(names(df) == "a")))
```

---

**8)** Or another option is `melt` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df), measure = patterns("a", "b"), 
   value.name = c("a", "b"))[, variable := NULL][]
```

NOTE: Make sure the datasets are created with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:4,
             b = 5:8,
             a.1 = letters[1:4],
             b.1 = letters[5:8],
             a.2 = LETTERS[1:4],
             b.2 = LETTERS[5:8], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
names(df)[c(1,3,5)] <- "a"
names(df)[c(2,4,6)] <- 'b'
```